# asp.net core приложение

Tags: веб-программирование, asp.net, маршрутизация, веб-сайт

Пишу приложение в Visual Studio на asp.net, вроде всё настроил корректно, и путь прописан правильно, но почему-то не хочет открывать начальную страницу сайта, пишет, что не может найти класс, хотя он есть. Помогите пожалуйста, а то уже несколько дней мучаюсь
Вот ошибка:
InvalidOperationException: The view 'Index' was not found. The following locations were searched: /Views/Home/Index.cshtml /Views/Shared/Index.cshtml

Index.cshtml у меня находится в /Views/Home/

На картинке классы и маршрут до Index.cshtml
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]